# IIS Virtual directory 404 when try to browse any file

Tags: .net, iis, iis-7.5, hosting, windows-server-2008

I have an application in .net core.I have hosted the app in IIS. Now when I add virtual directory within this application and try to browse files it gives me 404.
But if I make a separate website for browsing images it works fine.I want the website and file browsing together on one single website.I am using IIS 7.5 and windows server 2008 R2.

Comment: Did you try browsing the directory from within your IIS program or typing in the url of the directory manually in a browser?

Comment: i tried both. Everytime it is showing 404.But if i make separate site for file browsing its working fine.

Comment: Maybe make sure permission on virtual directory allows the IIS User to access that folder.  Also is the virtual directory folder used on multiple applications?

Comment: Maybe this link can help. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/248033/how-system-administrators-can-troubleshoot-an-http-404-file-not-found

Comment: Do you have `app.UseStaticFiles()` within `Startup.Configure` method?

Comment: Your first step should be identify the sub-status code of 404.

Open IIS logs - C:\inetpub\logs\logfiles\w3svc_websiteID and check for the substatus code. Please share it here once you identify that.